# Data frame header in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make some calculations with data from oracle db using R. I connected to the DB and extracted the data correctly.

```
> y=dbGetQuery(con, "select distinct(fk_parametro) from t_datos")
> y

FK_PARAMETRO
1            30
2            42
3            43
4            83
5            87
6             1
7             6
8            44
9            20
10           14
11           86
12           88
13           85
14           81
15           35
16            8
17           80
18           89
19            7
20           12
21           82
22            9
23           10
```

The following command.. works:

```
> sum(y)
[1] 1042
```

But this one.. fails:

```
> mean(y)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I think it happens because R is considering the header "FK_PARAMETRO" as an element. can someone help me to figure out?

Comment: You may need `mean(y[,1])`  As an example `y <-  data.frame(1:10); mean(y)#[1] NA` and `mean(y[,1])#[1] 5.5`

Comment: Two things: you are trying to take the mean of a df not specific column. Also, your query seems to be pulling out a foreign key from database. Why would you run aggregates (sum, mean, etc.) on key fields? Modes and counts might be more relevant. You could even run the aggregates in Oracle query, grouped by FK (giving you distinct FKs): `select fk_parametro, Sum(qtyfield), Avg(qtyfield), Count(qtyfield) from t_datos group by fk_parametro`

Comment: Parfait. I only wanted to test.. My code does not use the column "FK_PARAMETRO" for these calculations actually.  mean(y[,1]) works perfectly. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @akrun, this works

```
mean(y[,1])
```

Or as suggested by @PierreLafortune, could also do

```
colMeans(y)
```

Comment: i didnt wait nothing. To be honest. I dont know yet what the problems with the answers is.. by the way.. Thanks again. Bye.

Comment: It's okay.  Not a problem.